# Regression Loop By Date

Tags: r, loops, regression

Below is a 100 row sample of the data I'm working with:

```
    structure(list(`Team Code` = c(107, 277, 129, 1320, 27, 694, 
231, 306, 314, 465, 164, 380, 295, 440, 367, 458, 428, 528, 574, 
772, 648, 736, 473, 650, 667, 732, 140, 695, 718, 749, 731, 758, 
490, 786, 14, 86, 153, 688, 156, 157, 244, 416, 327, 674, 204, 
432, 254, 47, 508, 51, 30, 709, 690, 725, 466, 90, 108, 529, 
110, 697, 147, 37, 202, 559, 207, 754, 2, 721, 228, 415, 236, 
726, 255, 67, 257, 457, 277, 418, 290, 392, 331, 539, 355, 742, 
365, 796, 31, 366, 235, 400, 312, 414, 43, 716, 434, 768, 301, 
454, 469, 626), `Opponent Code` = c(277, 107, 1320, 129, 694, 
27, 306, 231, 465, 314, 380, 164, 440, 295, 458, 367, 528, 428, 
772, 574, 736, 648, 650, 473, 732, 667, 695, 140, 749, 718, 758, 
731, 786, 490, 86, 14, 688, 153, 157, 156, 416, 244, 674, 327, 
432, 204, 47, 254, 51, 508, 709, 30, 725, 690, 90, 466, 529, 
108, 697, 110, 37, 147, 559, 202, 754, 207, 721, 2, 415, 228, 
726, 236, 67, 255, 457, 257, 418, 277, 392, 290, 539, 331, 742, 
355, 796, 365, 366, 31, 400, 235, 414, 312, 716, 43, 768, 434, 
454, 301, 626, 469), Year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016), Date = structure(c(17040, 
17040, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 
17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 
17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 
17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17045, 17046, 17046, 17046, 
17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 
17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 17046, 
17046, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 
17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 
17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 
17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 
17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047, 17047
), class = "Date"), HomeTeam = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), Points = c(51, 31, 49, 3, 13, 20, 13, 34, 
13, 63, 24, 21, 20, 17, 70, 14, 30, 23, 14, 46, 13, 10, 48, 21, 
0, 24, 28, 7, 3, 7, 45, 6, 48, 14, 22, 16, 7, 33, 7, 44, 13, 
28, 13, 26, 61, 14, 21, 31, 7, 55, 10, 31, 13, 28, 30, 27, 28, 
53, 24, 31, 19, 13, 24, 45, 45, 42, 21, 37, 3, 70, 16, 52, 17, 
14, 33, 24, 3, 63, 13, 52, 13, 33, 13, 36, 14, 16, 21, 20, 24, 
7, 45, 21, 17, 57, 11, 26, 52, 3, 0, 31), OppPoints = c(31, 51, 
3, 49, 20, 13, 34, 13, 63, 13, 21, 24, 17, 20, 14, 70, 23, 30, 
46, 14, 10, 13, 21, 48, 24, 0, 7, 28, 7, 3, 6, 45, 14, 48, 16, 
22, 33, 7, 44, 7, 28, 13, 26, 13, 14, 61, 31, 21, 55, 7, 31, 
10, 28, 13, 27, 30, 53, 28, 31, 24, 13, 19, 45, 24, 42, 45, 37, 
21, 70, 3, 52, 16, 14, 17, 24, 33, 63, 3, 52, 13, 33, 13, 36, 
13, 16, 14, 20, 21, 7, 24, 21, 45, 57, 17, 26, 11, 3, 52, 31, 
0)), row.names = c(1489L, 1490L, 297L, 298L, 1453L, 1454L, 1915L, 
1916L, 2121L, 2122L, 2651L, 2652L, 3425L, 3426L, 3535L, 3536L, 
4759L, 4760L, 5077L, 5078L, 5405L, 5406L, 5421L, 5422L, 5771L, 
5772L, 6239L, 6240L, 6845L, 6846L, 7537L, 7538L, 7813L, 7814L, 
355L, 356L, 489L, 490L, 509L, 510L, 1135L, 1136L, 2175L, 2176L, 
3317L, 3318L, 3755L, 3756L, 4293L, 4294L, 6607L, 6608L, 6993L, 
6994L, 8043L, 8044L, 85L, 86L, 145L, 146L, 381L, 382L, 815L, 
816L, 893L, 894L, 899L, 900L, 909L, 910L, 1129L, 1130L, 1263L, 
1264L, 1353L, 1354L, 1499L, 1500L, 1671L, 1672L, 2301L, 2302L, 
2409L, 2410L, 2469L, 2470L, 2475L, 2476L, 2789L, 2790L, 2933L, 
2934L, 3315L, 3316L, 3415L, 3416L, 3449L, 3450L, 3735L, 3736L
), class = "data.frame")
```

The full data set is about 8000 observations with about 500 different statistics on the game listed. I am attempting to get an adjusted cumulative mean for each team stat for a given point in time. For example, a team on 10/1 may have a cumulative mean of 45.0 for the points per game stat over the 5 games they've played; however, I want to adjust this number for strength of schedule using a ridge regression. The theory behind this comes from the following [article](https://medium.com/analyzing-ncaa-college-basketball-with-gcp/fitting-it-in-adjusting-team-metrics-for-schedule-strength-4e8239be0530). I essentially need a loop that does the following:

1. For every unique date in the data set, we filter the data set for every date previous as well as one stat at a time. We also need to group the data by season (Year column) so we only bring in that seasons data. (We could run a loop for every row, but since dates are duplicated, I figured a loop by date rather than row would yield quicker results). Example from sample data (temp) for Points and 2016-09-02.

   ```
   temp <- filter(temp, temp$Date < "2016-09-02")
   temp <- select(temp, c(-OppPoints))
   ```
2. The loop then needs to create dummy variables for both the "Team Code" and "Opponent Code" columns and run a ridge regression model on all of the dummy variables and HomeTeam as the independent variables and the stat in question as the dependent variable. Continuing with 2016-09-02 example:

   ```
   temp <- dummy_cols(temp, select_columns = 'Team Code')
   temp <- dummy_cols(temp, select_columns = 'Opponent Code')
   temp <- subset(temp, select = -c(`Team Code`,`Opponent Code`, Year, Date))
   temp_Ridge <- lm.ridge(Points ~ ., temp)
   ```
3. Then for the date we are looping on (2016-09-02). We now have coefficient values for each team code and opponent code. I can now get an adjusted cumulative Points stat for each team by taking their specific coefficient and adding the intercept to it. I then need the loop to create a data frame where we have the following columns: Date, Stat_Name, Team Code, Ridge_Regression_Coefficient, Adjusted_"Stat Name". Example for 2016-09-02 for team code 27 would be an adjusted stat of 19.1395541 (intercept = 23.08317512 + team code 27 coefficient of -3.30332078). So the table would be 2016-09-02,Points,27,-3.30332078, 19.1395541.
4. Then of course the loop would go back and do the same for 2016-09-02 for OppPoints this time, add to the table, then move onto the next date for all of the stats, and add them to the table, etc.

I know this is probably confusing, so please feel free to ask any questions in the comments. Really appreciate everyone's help ahead of time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to finally work. Code is below:

```
Data$Date <- as.Date(Data$Date)
    Data$Stat_Name <- colnames(Data[,6:7])
    Season_Stats <- unique(subset(Data, select = c(Year,Date,Stat_Name)))
    reg_results_collection <- data.frame(Coef_Name = character(),
                                         Year = numeric(),
                                         Date = as.Date(character()),
                                         Stat_Name = character(),
                                         Ridge_Reg_Coef = numeric(),
                                         Adj_Stat_Value = numeric())
    
    for (i in 1:nrow(Season_Stats)) {
      tryCatch({
      date <- Season_Stats[i, "Date"]
      year <- Season_Stats[i, "Year"]
      stat_name1 <- Season_Stats[i, "Stat_Name"]
      this_season_game_stat <- filter(Data, Data$Year == year, Data$Date < date)
      this_season_game_stat <- dplyr::select(this_season_game_stat, c("Team Code","Opponent Code","HomeTeam",stat_name1))
      this_season_game_stat <- dummy_columns(this_season_game_stat, select_columns = c("Team Code","Opponent Code"), remove_selected_columns = TRUE)
      this_season_game_stat <- na.omit(this_season_game_stat)
      reg.fit <- lm.ridge(paste(stat_name1, "~ ."), this_season_game_stat)
      this_reg_results <- data.frame(Year = year,
                                     Date = date,
                                     Stat_Name = stat_name1,
                                     Ridge_Reg_Coef = coef(reg.fit))
      this_reg_results <- setDT(this_reg_results, keep.rownames = TRUE)
      this_reg_results_intercept <- as.numeric(this_reg_results[1,5])
      this_reg_results$Adj_Stat_Value <- this_reg_results$Ridge_Reg_Coef + this_reg_results_intercept
      this_reg_results <- this_reg_results[-c(1,2)]
      colnames(this_reg_results)[1] <- "Coef_Name"
      reg_results_collection <- unique(rbind(reg_results_collection,this_reg_results))
    },error=function(e){cat("ERROR :",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
    }
```